# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I tried deleting an item from a table with AJAX via a POST call.

```
///// DELETE INDIVIDUAL ROW IN A TABLE /////
jQuery('.stdtable .delete').live('click', function (e) {
//var newsId1 = $(this).attr("title");

e.preventDefault();

var p = jQuery(this).parents('tr');

if (p.next().hasClass('togglerow'))
   p.next().remove();

p.fadeOut(function () {
    jQuery(this).remove();
});

$.ajax({
  URL: "/AdminPanel/News/DeleteNews",
  data: { "newsId": 1 },
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  success: function (msg) {
  alert(msg);
}
});
```

In this code I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined**.

Comment: Note that live() is deprecated and removed from later versions of jQuery

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you try doing what the rest of the code is doing, using `jQuery`

```
jQuery.ajax({
  URL: "/AdminPanel/News/DeleteNews",
  data: { "newsId": 1 },
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  success: function (msg) {
  alert(msg);
}
```

You can wrap your code in a DOM ready function that sets the value of `$` locally in the function scope, that way you can always use `$`

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // code goes here
});
```

Comment: Thanks o lot, @adeneo. I knew this, but didn't think as you)

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you @adeneo!

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve the problem using `jQuery` instead of `$`.

In my case, I add the source `jQuery.js` and solve the problem, like

```html
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/JS/jQuery.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: buddy, try to use js labriraies and frameworks,, I asked this question 6 years ago)))

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my handling project, it connects js labriraies failed so I use this method.