# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined When I'm trying to send data to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have created a form to get feedback from user, I’m simply trying to send form data to url, but I’m getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

```
function sendData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "www.yashkjhsah.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: $(".contacts_form").serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            alert(data);
            if(data!="Error in Insert Query!")
            {
                alert("Thank you for Enquiry we will send answer in your Mail.");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error while saving the data");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Include jQuery _before_ your code.

Comment: you want me to include jQuery insted of $   ?

Comment: No, include the thing that is commonly known as jQuery, that defines `$`.

Comment: you are not loading in time jquery, read my answer please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588941/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-ajax-of-undefined)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I solved it, by changing the dollar symbol $ with **jQuery**.

```js
 jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "...",
                data: jQuery('myForm').serialize(),
                success: function(msg) {
                    console.log('success!');
                },
            });
```

Comment: This answer helped in solving my code issue. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

The error message says that jQuery is not define.
You must include jQuery before doing anything with $.ajax

Put this line in the html page before your script :
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

That means that jquery has not been loaded.

Make sure that you have the script in your html, and also wrap the call to this function `sendData` inside a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//do stuff
})
```